# aframe state component - pass data from state to component

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am making use of aframe-state-component to build a game and tracking the game level and play/pause status through the state variables.

I am looking to understand how to pass state data to a component with properties.

Here is my state -

```
AFRAME.registerState({
  initialState: {
    score: 0
  },
 handlers: {
    gamePaused: function(state) {
      state.gamePaused = true;
    },
    gameStarted: function(state, event) {
     state.gamePaused = false;            
     state.level = event.source;     
    }
  }
});
```

and I pass the level to gameStarted handler by emitting an event in my angular controller -

```
el.emit('gameStarted', {source: levelnumber}, true);
```

and here is my html

```
<a-entity bind__model-subset="target: #orca; gamelevel: level"></a-entity>
```

the component "model-subset" originally accepted only "target" property. I included gamelevel property in there so that I can pass the state variable level to this component. Thereafter I modified, the model-subset component to include the gamelevel property in the schema as shown below -

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('model-subset', {
  schema: {
    target: { default: '', type: 'selector' },
    gamelevel: { type: 'number'}
  },
  init: function() {
    var data = this.data;
    var el = this.el;
    console.log("model-subset level is ", data.gamelevel); //this component does not get executed
  }
})
```

But, it errors out and the component code does not get executed. Could you please give me an example of how to pass state data to different components that already have a few properties in their schema?

Comment: Added an answer. I just edited it because I messed up the formatting on the code section and it wasn't showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good question.

In a `bind__` component, you only pass state properties, not any real values. Real values go in the component defininition itself. So move `target: #orca` out into `model-subset` since that's just a value.

```
<a-entity bind__model-subset="gamelevel: level" model-subset="target: #orca"></a-entity>
```

Comment: Okay, so should "model-subset" component include the property gamelevel in its schema for the value of level to be accessible inside it via this.data.gamelevel?               AFRAME.registerComponent('model-subset', {
  schema: {
    target: { default: '', type: 'selector' },
    gamelevel: {default: 2, type: 'number'}
  },
  init: function() {
    var data = this.data;
    var el = this.el;
    console.log("model-subset level is ", data.gamelevel); } });

Comment: yeah it needs that property still. the bind will just automatically set for you when state changeds.

Comment: Yup, works perfectly fine. You are awesome and I will buy you a brewery.

Comment: A beer, or a whole brewery? xD

Comment: Although your help is worth a whole brewery, I now realize I spoke in excitement and can only afford to buy a few beers :-(

Comment: Haha no worries, I wasn't going to hold you to a whole brewery.